# Matplotlib remove vertical lines when plotting catgegorical variables against numberical variables

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I am trying to plot numerical and binary categorical variables on the same plot. For some reason, I see vertical lines where the scatter plot would normally be. Below is my graph:
[image]

Here is the code I used to produce the graph:

```
ln = plt.plot(on_task, valence, "r")
plt.yticks(np.arange(1, 10, step=1))
plt.xticks(np.arange(0, 2, step=1))
plt.ylabel("Valence")
plt.xlabel("Off-task Bin")
plt.grid(False)
plt.savefig("./data/valence_on_task.png")
plt.show()
```

Note that valence is from 1-9 and on_task is boolean from 0 to 1.

I tried using seaborn to plot with regplot but the line is straight...

```
sns.regplot(x="off_task_bin", y="valence", data=df)
plt.yticks(np.arange(1, 10, step=1))
plt.xticks(np.arange(0, 2, step=1))
plt.ylabel("Valence")
plt.xlabel("Off-task Bin")
plt.grid(False)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: `plt.scatter(on_task, valence)`?

Comment: @QuangHoang I am not looking to get a scatter plot but rather a linear fit to the scattered data

Comment: how are you gonna do a linear fit for this data? It doesn't really make sense. What output are you expecting?

Comment: @cripcate something similar to the first graph without the vertical lines at 0 and 1 respectively

Comment: @APorter1031 Then shouldn't it be `sns.regplot(x='valence', y="off_task_bin", data=df)`?